# state object values won't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, dropdown

I trying to use react to create  a dropdown menu of movie names.
whenever the dropdown menu selection changes the value of the "currentMovie" state should be updated by comparing the  value to the object id in the "movies" array state

here is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import MovieComp from './Movie';

function ParentComp(props) {
  
const [movies, setMovies] = useState( [ { id : 1 , name : "Under the Dome", pic :
      "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/81/202627.jpg" },
      { id : 2 , name : "Person of Interest", pic :
      "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/163/407679.jpg" },
      { id : 3 , name : "Bitten", pic :
      "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/15.jpg" } ] )

  const [currentMovie, setCurrentMovie] = useState( {id : "" , name : "", pic : "" } )

  function createDropMenu() {
    return movies.map( item => {
      return <option key={item.id} value={item.id} > {item.name} </option>
    } )
  }

  function updateMovie(e) {
    if (e.target.value === 0) {
      console.log("test")
      let selectedMovie = {id : "" , name : "", pic : "" };
      let selectedMovieEntries = Object.entries(selectedMovie);
      selectedMovieEntries.map( entry => {
        setCurrentMovie( prev => ( {...prev, [ entry[0] ]: entry[1] } ) );
      })
      
    } else {
      console.log("test")
      let selectedMovie = movies.find( item => item.id === e.target.value );
      let selectedMovieCopy = {};
      selectedMovieCopy = {...selectedMovie};
      let selectedMovieEntries = Object.entries(selectedMovieCopy);
      selectedMovieEntries.map( entry => {
        setCurrentMovie( prev => ( {...prev, [ entry[0] ]: entry[1] } ) );
      }) 
    }
  }

  return (
    <div  >
      <h3> Pick a movie: </h3> 
      <select onChange={updateMovie}>
        <option value={0} ></option>
        {createDropMenu()}
      </select> <br/>

      <MovieComp name = {currentMovie.name} pic = {currentMovie.pic} /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParentComp;
```

for some reason the currentMovie state doesn't change it's values when changing the selection
what am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't need to create a copy of the selected movie object.  Did you try `setCurrentMovie(selectedMovie)`?

Answer (score 0):

This produces an empty array:

```
let selectedMovieEntries = Object.entries(selectedMovie);
```

So `.map()` simply never iterates over the array and `setCurrentMovie` is never invoked.

Taking a step back... `updateMovie` appears to be drastically over-engineered.  If all you need to know is which "movie" is "currently selected" then that's nothing more than the `id` of that "movie" record.  For example:

```
// Initial state is undefined, since nothing is selected
const [currentMovie, setCurrentMovie] = useState()

// later...
// Then in the JSX just update state with the selected value
<select onChange={e => setCurrentMovie(e.target.value)}>
```

(Note: This is untested, and you *may* need to convert to a numeric value here as well as `e.target.value` could be a string.)

At that point you don't need the entirety of that `updateMovie` function at all.  Then any time you need to get the currently selected movie, just fetch it from that list.  For example:

```
<MovieComp movie={movies.find(m => m.id === currentMovie)} />
```

Or if that component really needs two separate props for some reason, get the current movie on render:

```
const selectedMovie = movies.find(m => m.id === currentMovie);
```

And use that in the markup:

```
<MovieComp name={currentMovie?.name} pic={currentMovie?.pic} />
```

The benefit here is that you're no longer duplicating data in state.  The "current movie" is just a reference back to the data, not a copy of the data.